# Django: simulate HTTP requests in shell

Tags: django, django-shell

I just learnt that with Rails is possible to simulate HTTP requests in the console with few lines of code.

Check out: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3176-three-quick-rails-console-tips (section "Dive into your app").

Is there a similar way to do that with Django? Would be handy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How I simulate requests from the python command line is:

- Use the excellent [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)
- Use the django [reverse function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse)

A simple way of simulating requests is:

```
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get(reverse('app.views.your_view'))
>>> r.text
(prints output)
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Update: be sure to launch the django shell (via `manage.py shell`), not a classic python shell.

Update 2: For Django <1.10, change the first line to

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

Comment: I get this when I try out your method: `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///?`

Comment: You might want to prepend `"http://localhost:8000"` so that it reads `requests.get("http://192.168.0.1:8000" + reverse(...))`

Comment: I am getting this error `[Errno 111] Connection refused` although I can connect with my browser.

Comment: This isn't doing anything different then just requesting it via the command line with `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: Use `django.urls` for django 1.10+. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/

Comment: the question was how to simulate requests, not how to create requests

Comment: I had trouble with users and sessions. I managed to ser up the request user, but the request session always fails and the template render doesn't go through.

Comment: and what about POST request?

Answer (score 54):

You can use `RequestFactory`, which allows

- inserting a user into the request
- inserting an uploaded file into the request
- sending specific parameters to the view

and does not require the additional dependency of using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Note that you have to specify both the URL and the view class, so it takes an extra line of code than using requests.

```
from django.test import RequestFactory

request_factory = RequestFactory()
my_url = '/my_full/url/here'  # Replace with your URL -- or use reverse
my_request = request_factory.get(my_url)
response = MyClasBasedView.as_view()(my_request)  # Replace with your view
response.render()
print(response)
```

To set the user of the request, do something like `my_request.user = User.objects.get(id=123)` before getting the response.

To send parameters to a class-based view, do something like  `response = MyClasBasedView.as_view()(my_request, parameter_1, parameter_2)`

**Extended Example**

Here's an example of using `RequestFactory` with these things in combination

- HTTP POST (to url `url`, functional view `view`, and a data dictionary `post_data`)
- uploading a single file (path `file_path`, name `file_name`, and form field value `file_key`)
- assigning a user to the request (`user`)
- passing on kwargs dictionary from the url (`url_kwargs`)

`SimpleUploadedFile` helps format the file in a way that is valid for forms.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.test import RequestFactory

request = RequestFactory().post(url, post_data)
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_ptr:
    request.FILES[file_key] = SimpleUploadedFile(file_name, file_ptr.read())
    file_ptr.seek(0)  # resets the file pointer after the read
    if user:
        request.user = user
    response = view(request, **url_kwargs)
```

**Using RequestFactory from a Python shell**

`RequestFactory` names your server "testserver" by default, which can cause a problem if you're not using it inside test code.  You'll see an error like:

```
DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'testserver'. You may need to add 'testserver' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

This workaround from @boatcoder's comment shows how to override the default server name to "localhost":

```
request_factory = RequestFactory(**{"SERVER_NAME": "localhost", "wsgi.url_scheme":"https"}).
```

Comment: There are some drawbacks to the RequestFactory, namely that it names your server `testserver` which can then cause issues with `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, you can fix that though by initializing it like this `rf = RequestFactory(**{"SERVER_NAME": "localhost", "wsgi.url_scheme":"https"})`.

Comment: I tried to create a post request with RequestFactory (regarding a login page), how can I fix this error: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Comment: Try this `my_request._dont_enforce_csrf_checks = True` and let us know if that works.  If it does I'll edit my response.

Answer (score 5):

(See tldr; down)

Its an old question,
but just adding an answer, in case someone maybe interested.

Though this might not be the best(or lets say Django) way of doing things.
but you can try doing this way.

Inside your django shell

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('your_full_url_here')
```

**Explanation:**
I omitted the `reverse()`, 
explanation being, since `reverse()` more or less,
finds the url associated to a views.py function,
you may omit the `reverse()` if you wish to, and put the whole url instead.

For example, if you have a friends app in your django project, 
and you want to see the `list_all()` (in views.py) function in the friends app, 
then you may do this.

**TLDR;**

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://localhost:8000/friends/list_all'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases, this just works:

```
from django.test import Client  
c = Client()
c.get("/").content
```

but it requires "testserver" in ALLOWED_HOSTS