# Django Rest Framework api test upload text file application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to test my Django REST API for file uploading.

The catch is that my server tries to validate the file so that the file has a recognised file type. Currently only text-based filetypes are allowed, like: docs, pdf, txt.

I've tried using a temporary file and now I just tried to read a file from the disk then gave up.

Whenever I use a temporary file the server responds with:

```
    {
        "cover_letter": [
            "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
        ],
        "manuscript": [
            "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
        ]
    }
```

This is my test:

```
 def test_user_can_submit_a_paper(self):
     """
         Ensure that an user is able to upload a paper.

         This test is not working.. yet
     """
     tmp_file = open("__init__.py", "w")
     data = {
         "title": "paper",
         "authors": "me",
         "description": "ma detailed description",
         "manuscript": base64.b64encode(tmp_file.read()).decode(),
         "cover_letter": base64.b64encode(tmp_file.read()).decode()
     }
     tmp_file.close()


     response = self.client.post(self.papers_submitted, data=urlencode(MultiValueDict(data)), content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                 HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=self.authorization_header)
     print(response.data)
     self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

     del data["cover_letter"]
     response = self.client.post(self.papers_submitted, data=urlencode(MultiValueDict(data)), content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                 HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=self.authorization_header)
     print(response.data)
     self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have successfully tested this endpoint via postman but I don't know how to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you'd like to test your DRF endpoint with a file upload, using python.  You should use `RequestFactory`, which simulates a request -- it will be more like using Postman.

This answer [Django: simulate HTTP requests in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756800/django-simulate-http-requests-in-shell/38596606#38596606) has an example of using `RequestFactory`, and there are multiple answers here [django RequestFactory file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540446/django-requestfactory-file-upload) for specific solutions on how to include uploaded files with `RequestFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a solution thanks to Mark's answer.
Here's the code if anyone is interested:

```
def test_user_can_submit_a_paper(self):
    from api.journal import PaperListSubmitted
    from django.test.client import RequestFactory
    from django.core.files import temp as tempfile
    """
        Ensure that an user is able to upload a paper.
    """

    request_factory = RequestFactory()
    manuscript = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt")
    cover_letter = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt")
    manuscript.write(b"This is my stupid paper that required me to research writing this test for over 5h")
    cover_letter.write(b"This is my stupid paper that required me to research writing this test for over 5h")
    manuscript.seek(0)
    cover_letter.seek(0)

    post_data = {
        "title": "My post title",
        "description": "this is my paper description",
        "authors": "no authors",
        "manuscript": manuscript,
        "cover_letter": cover_letter
    }

    request = request_factory.post(self.papers_submitted, HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=self.authorization_header,
                                   data=post_data)

    response = PaperListSubmitted.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```